# copying custom field value from sale order line to stock.move in odoo

Tags: odoo-10

Copying value from sale order line to stock move it shows only second row value in both rows. code:
[enter image description here][1]

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class StockMove(models.Model):

@api.multi
    def get_data(self):
        data = self.env['sale.order.line'].search([])
        print("Get Data Function")
        for rec in data:
            print(rec.x_serialnumber)
            for record in self:
                record.x_serialnumber = rec.x_serialnumber

    _inherit = 'stock.move'
    x_serialnumber = fields.Text(string="Serial Number", compute='get_data')"
```

On Sale order line it shows like this:

Serial Number: in both lines

112233

445566

But in stock move:

Serial Number: in both lines

445566

445566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurangzaib 
Update your code:

```
@api.multi
def get_data(self):
    for move in self:
        if not (move.picking_id and move.picking_id.group_id):
            continue
        picking = move.picking_id
        sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([
            ('procurement_group_id', '=', picking.group_id.id)], limit=1)
        for line in sale_order.order_line:
            if line.product_id.id != move.product_id.id:
                continue
            move.update({
                'x_serialnumber': line.x_serialnumber,
            })
```